# demonstration on modulo operation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I would like to prove that if :

$a = m\,(\text{mod}\,n)$, then $a$ is equal to $GCD(m,n)$ or a multiple of $GCD(m,n)$

I am starting by : $m=a+kn$ but after ?

Could anyone know how to prove it ?

Thanks

Comment: sorry, I forgot to say that a is a prime number, I updated my question

Comment: Why is $a$ prime?

Comment: this is the assertion to demonstrate, we auppose that $a$ is a prime number  and it exists m and n so that a = m (mod n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is also true if $a$ is not prime. Recall that $a\equiv m $ mod $n$ iff $a-m=nk$ for some integer $k$. Let $d = \text{gcd}(m,n)$. Then $d$ divides both $nk$ and $m$, so $d$ also divides $nk+m=a$.

Comment: VincentBoelens: Thanks, evidently, and what about if $a$ is a prime number : let's take 2 different prime numbers $p1$ and $p2$ with same $m$, $n$, I have : $d$ divides $p1$ and $d$ divides $p2$. But $p1$ and $p2$ are prime, so $d$ must be equal to 1 = $GCD(m,n)$ because $p1$ and $p2$ are different, is this exact ?

Comment: I suppose above there is an infinity of prime numbers congruent to $n$ modulo $m$.

Comment: @youpilat13 Yes, this reasoning looks correct to me.